# android sharedPreferences xml file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an example that already has an xml file for preferences. I can find its location, download to desktop, modify and so on. However, I am an Android newbie and not able to know when and how this preference file is created. Thinking about iOS, you can set a plist file and then work with nsuserdefaults and userstandards.

EDIT: I want to copy xml file from resources directly to shared_prefs and then get its values!Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Shared preferences, you need to use 2 global variables.

```
SharedPreferences sp;
public static String filename = "filename";
```

and then you initialize it with

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

to add something to it, use something like this, although the type can be `boolean`, `float`, `long` or `int` also, and `key` is an unique identifier and `name` is the string variable to save

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key", name);
editor.commit();
```

and to retrieve it use something like, with `null` being the default value if no value has been saved for that `key` yet

```
String string = sp.getString("key", null);
```

Comment: Thank you but I would know how to attach xml file to shared_prefs without setting it. I would like to copy xml file from resources directly to shared_prefs and then get its values!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean where is the `xml` using the `adb` shell, you can check the `xml` of `SharedPreferences`. You can find it in the folder `data/data`.